# StackExchange.Redis gives Timeout Exception on LTRIM

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

The following gives me a timeout exception. `ListLength` and `ListRange` commands work perfectly fine.

```
public static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureRedisConnectionString"].ToString();
        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connStr);
    });

public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
{
    get
    {
        return lazyConnection.Value;
    }
}

public static IDatabase RedisDb
{
    get
    {
        return Connection.GetDatabase();
    }
}

db.ListTrim("MyKeyName", 0, 4);
```

The exception is:

> Timeout performing LTRIM MyKeyName, inst: 0, mgr: ExecuteSelect, err:
>   never, queue: 1, qu: 1, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 1, in: 0, ar: 0,
>   IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=1,Free=1022,Min=4,Max=1023), clientName: HS-PC at
>   StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message
>   message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line
>   1927 at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message,
>   ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisBase.cs:line
>   80 at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ListTrim(RedisKey key, Int64
>   start, Int64 stop, CommandFlags flags) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:line
>   796}  System.SystemException {System.TimeoutException}